Trouble exporting high poly mesh from blender to Substance Painter
I am trying to export a high poly sculpted mesh from blender and use it to create a normal map within Substance Painter.  For reasons unknown the details do not come over.  Am I supposed to bake the high poly first or something I am unfamiliar with the workflow from blender to Substance Painter this way.  FYI, low poly I brought from Maya into blender as FBX, fully unwrapped prior.  Then converted into high poly using the Multisolution modifier, sculpted and then tried to export.  If I can get the high poly out correctly then use it as the _high in SP it should be a piece of cake.

Hello and welcome, did you apply the modifier? Blender modifier are proprietary and export tools not always work as intended
